# What are the benefits of the Test Data Builder pattern over Object Initializers?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've been reading a bunch of [blog](http://elegantcode.com/2008/04/26/test-data-builders-refined/) [posts](http://geekswithblogs.net/Podwysocki/archive/2008/01/08/118362.aspx) espousing the virtues of the Test Data Builder Pattern. It seems like a good idea, but all of the posts are years old.

When C# introduced [Object Initializes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx), did it make the Test Data Builder pattern obsolete?

Before Object Initializers, you would have needed the following code to initialize a person object:

```
Person p = new Person("John", "Doe", "555-555-1234");
```

At the time, having a builder would have cleaned up the code like this:

```
Person person = new PersonBuilder()
        .WithFirstName("John")
        .WithLastName("Doe")
        .WithPhoneNumber("555-555-1234");
```

Now with object initializers, it can look like this without writing any builder methods:

```
Person p = new Person() {FirstName="John", LastName="Doe", Phone="555-555-1234"};
```

In this simple example, it would seem that the builder pattern is not needed. Am I missing something? Do people still use the builder pattern? If so, what are the benefits?

Comment: Builders are still a good option when dealing with immutable objects for example.

Comment: Why voting to close this question? It's well written and interesting IMO.

Comment: @RogerAlsing if you expanded on that point it'd make a good answer.

Comment: @ken2k: I agree with you, but I imagine some would consider it subjective.

Comment: @DanPuzey I admit it is a bit subjective, I tried to ask for subjective benefits, but if you have some suggestions on how to make the question better, I'd appreciate the advice.

Comment: What if your sut doesn't expose these dependencies as properties, then you'll have to directly call the constructors, which is what you want to try to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases you can replace builders with object initializers.

However, there are a few cases where builders are still a good option.

Immutable objects is one example.
e.g. Jon Skeets protobuff implementation is a good example of real world builder pattern for immutable objects.
(https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/20/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-1-messages-builders-and-immutability/)

```
Person john = new Person.Builder()
    .SetFirstName("John")
    .SetLastName("Doe")
    .Build(); //creates an immutable person
```

Other cases might be to apply preset values.
eg.

```
Rectangle rect = RectangleBuilder.MakeSquare(10).Build();
Car car = CarBuilder.MakeVolvo().PimpIt().SetColor(Color.Red).Build();
```

In this case you might set multiple properties at once so you can start from a prototype of some sort and continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

Take StringBuilder for example. it is still useful and required in order to build a new string
with high performance (As optimizations in the compiler will not cover all scenarios).
Same goes for other immutable objects, as was comented already.

Also, when using a builder pattern , it is easier to replace the initalized type, which give you loose coupling (for dependency injection).
It may not always be required for test purposes, but might still come in handy at times.

Comment: To expand on the second point, it is always wise (for the purposes of loose coupling & unit tests) to delegate object creation to dedicated factories and builders. This way, when you come to write your tests, you can inject factories that produce mocks/stubs.